# How do I merge files without conflict in git?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull, git-diff

We are two people working on one master branch repo in Github.

And, today I had modified a file in my local copy which I commited, then I wanted to merge my friends change with he pushed to github, so I did:

```
git fetch
git diff --stat HEAD...HEAD@{upstream}
```

And I can see

```
 src/components/views/invoicing/expenses/add.vue  | 106 ++++++--------
 src/components/views/invoicing/expenses/edit.vue | 173 ++++++++++++-----------
 src/components/views/org/Add.vue                 |   4 +-
 src/i18n/de.js                                   |  22 ++-
 src/i18n/en.js                                   |  26 ++--
 src/i18n/fr.js                                   |  11 +-
 src/resources/expensesList.js                    |   4 +-
```

Now, I can merge all files since I didn't modify them except the `src/resources/expensesList.js` file which I have modified and committed.

So, `git merge origin/master` say:

> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/resources/expensesList.js

but all the other files are mergable and okay, so is there anyway to fix the conflict either to instruct git to use my changes or the incoming changes so I can run merge without conflict

Comment: Yeah and whats the point? Just go ahead and merge it.

Comment: it can't merge because it's in conflict

Comment: it's already telling you what to do. Start the mergetool and either merge or take your/theirs changes.

Comment: there are ways, but I'd suggest to not get used to them. Because it may end up with reverted good changes. Just resolve the confluct this time.

Comment: I'd try and come to terms that merging is necessary for distributed de-centralised version control

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/161813/1256452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when Git cannot merge automatically because of one or more conflicting file(s), it will abort the merge and put markers into the conflicting file(s) that will help you to resolve the conflict manually by making a decision for every single conflicting hunk of code about which version to keep. This behavior can be modified with the `-Xours` and `-Xtheirs` flags.

To merge and always use your version of a conflicting file, use:

```
git merge -Xours <branch>
```

To merge and always use the remote version (in this case, the version of your collaborator) of a conflicting file, use:

```
git merge -Xtheirs <branch>
```

For more details, see the [Git Tools - Advanced Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging) chapter in the Git documentation.

Comment: Can you expand a little on that? What does it mean `Xours` or `Xtheirs` and what do they do?